# Whats the fastest way to highlight different strings in an html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, highlight

I'm trying to search for strings in an html page, I have an object with 1000 names in it and I need to find if those names exist in the html document. If they do exist i then need to wrap them in a span or something and apply a class.

I've been using this [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) but it takes about 17 seconds to scan and highlight the whole page, this obviously varies depending on how many different names there are on the page.

I've tried a few different plugins but haven't found anything faster, is there a way to do this in vanilla JS that is faster? It only needs to work in Chrome.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: Structure of the object which holds names:

`var PEOPLE = {
  "fred" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  },
  "dave" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  },
  "bob" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  }
}`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the object structure that holds 1000 names?

Comment: You are probably using the plugin in a loop that runs _n_ times. You need a custom function that searches multiple strings at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain javascript.

Basically I iterate through your object and extract all the relevant names. Once I have this, I pass the array to the highlightString function where I join all the strings you want to match with the pipe character and create a regular expression that runs globally and ignores case. This results in the div being searched only being searched once. This should result in a considerable speedup.

```js
var PEOPLE = {
  "fred" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  },
  "dave" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  },
  "bob" : {
    loaded : false,
    elements : []
  }
},
name,
search = [];

for (name in PEOPLE) {
  search.push(name);
}    

function highlightStrings(input, toMatch) {
  var reg = new RegExp('(' + toMatch.join('|') + ')', "gi");
  input.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.replace(reg, '<span class="myHighLight">$1</span>');  
}

highlightStrings(document.getElementById("test"), search);
```

```css
.myHighLight {background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  test1 test2 fred test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 dave test10 test11 test12 bob test14 test15
</div>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Question was modified after I answered. Changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks for this @Calummm - I need to &0 to be the original string though rather than replaced with $0. Would this also work on document.body rather than an element with the id of test as I need to search the whole page?

Comment: $0 will match the matched string - so in this case it will simply wrap all matched strings with a span and not replace the matched string. In my example you can pass any element to the highlightStrings function so this will work fine with the document body. Do note however it will also match html tags.

Comment: in your example $0 replaces the matched string - I think possibly because it's inside quotes, does it need to be escaped? When I try it on the body I get ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to wrap the regular expression in brackets and use a $1 instead of a $0. I was at work and stuck with Internet Explorer and strangely it worked before.

Comment: Thanks @Calummm. It kind of works but breaks because for 2 reasons. Firstly because some of the names have special characters in so it's braking the RegEx. And secondly when I use it on the body tag I think it matches some html tags like you said and breaks the page.

Comment: I didn't have time to fully test but I'm marking it as the answer because I think it will solve the problem for other people. I'd love to get round to getting some benchmarks for different ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
        .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    }; // this is just for ignore case

    $("#id_of_Input_Tag").keyup(function() {
        $(".UserItem a").hide(); // hide all content 
        var rows = $(".UserItem").find("a");
        var data = this.value.split("~");
        $.each( data, function(i, v) {
            rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show(); // this will only show the maching content.
            if(v == '' ){
                $(".UserItem a").show(); // when input is empty then show all 

            }

        });

    });
```